# Squid refreshing freshness even with `override-expire`

Tags: squid

Goal: for the pattern given, cache the response for a given time, no matter what.

So far my `squid.conf` looks like this:

```
refresh_pattern -i \.git/info/refs 3600 100% 3600 ignore-reload ignore-no-store ignore-private override-expire override-lastmod
```

However, the freshness is still validated on every request:

```
1665672549.558    236 10.0.2.100 TCP_REFRESH_MODIFIED/200 771 GET https://github.com/appuio/component-openshift4-version.git/info/refs? - HIER_DIRECT/140.82.121.3 application/x-git-upload-pack-advertisement
1665672549.966    155 10.0.2.100 TCP_REFRESH_MODIFIED/200 782 GET https://github.com/appuio/component-openshift4-version.git/info/refs? - HIER_DIRECT/140.82.121.3 application/x-git-upload-pack-advertisement
1665673113.935    149 10.0.2.100 TCP_REFRESH_MODIFIED/200 783 GET https://github.com/appuio/component-openshift4-version.git/info/refs? - HIER_DIRECT/140.82.121.4 application/x-git-upload-pack-advertisement
1665673114.614    442 10.0.2.100 TCP_REFRESH_MODIFIED/200 777 GET https://github.com/appuio/component-openshift4-version.git/info/refs? - HIER_DIRECT/140.82.121.4 application/x-git-upload-pack-advertisement
```

How can I enforce squid to cache this URL for an hour?

Comment: the question mark is the problem ;) but in second do you intercept ssl?

Comment: I saw the question mark, but I don't anchor the regex (no `$`), so why does it matter? Yes, I do SSL bumping

Comment: because the question mark, marks the content to not static. I had to figure it out on my own. moreover I got the hint from the [squid manual](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/DynamicContent/Coordinator) additionally

Comment: If you place the new refresh_pattern _before_ the pattern that addresses the question mark (`refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?)`) then your pattern should work, provided that the server is not supplying a header that says that the content is not cache-able.  If the server has marked it as not being cache-able then you will need to turn on some `debug_options` to look at the HTTP headers and see what's up.